Is Mathematica enough powerful to simulate turbulence flow around a wing(3D) or a gas turbine blade?
I was searching and reading something about Mathematica and it was very interesting when realized it can simulate the fluid flow around solids but does anybody succeed to simulate turbulence flow around a wing(3D) or a gas turbine blade? (viscous and compressible)

Short: no
Longer: It depends on the Reynolds number and the amount of time you want to simulate. Then again, there is NO software in the world that can simulate the full compressible Navier–Stokes equations (without modeling small scales using LES, RANS, URANS or so) around a full wing of a 747 at cruising speeds…

Well, actually I'm talking about RANS and its turbulence modeling such as SP(Spallart-Almaras).
